# 99 Bottles of Beer - while + if + else if infinite loops JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, iteration

I am new to coding/programming and currently am taking online coding courses.  One of the challenges presented is to print the lyrics to the 99 bottles of beer song, I am assuming yall know the lyrics. I managed to come up with a solution (below).

The goal is to console log iterations from 99 to 0 while remaining grammatically correct.

My question is, why does setting while (endBeerCount >= 0) cause beer counts to go negative in an infinite loop?

Setting while (endBeerCount >= 1) fixes the infinite loop and correctly logs the lyrics.  Why does this condition not cause infinite loops?

Here is my code:

```
var beerCount = 99;
var endBeerCount = 98; 
function bottlesOfBeer() {
    while (endBeerCount >= 0) { // >=0 causes infinite loop (beer counts go negative). >=1 works 
        if (endBeerCount > 1) {
        console.log(beerCount + " bottles of beer on the wall " + beerCount + " bottles of beer." + 
          "Take one down and pass it around " + endBeerCount + " bottles of beer on the wall.");  
        beerCount--;
        endBeerCount--;
        }
        else if (endBeerCount = 1) {
            beerCount--;
            endBeerCount--;
            console.log(beerCount + " bottle of beer on the wall " + beerCount + " bottle of beer. "    
              + "Take one down and pass it around no more bottles of beer on the wall.");
        }
    }
    return console.log("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.  Go to the                             store and buy some more 99 bottles of beer on the wall."); 
}
```

Comment: `=` is for assigning a value to a variable. `==` and `===` are for comparisons. So `if (endBeerCount = 1)` **assigns** the value 1 to the variable.

Comment: btw, why two variables for almost the same?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193). When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result? What were the values used in that operation? What was the result? What result was expected? Why? To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and **its linked resources**

Comment: Ahhh, thank you Pointy!  That makes sense.  If I am understanding this correctly, when the if statement hits 1, the function looks at the else if statement, reassigns the endBeerCount to 1, and continues forever.  Is this correct?

Comment: re: Nina i have two values to track in the function. Rather than type beerCount - 1, I thought it makes more sense to me to just have another var so I know what it is at a glance.

Comment: Why do you run `beerCount--;
            endBeerCount--;` in both if branches?